# SetThreadExecutionState for another thread

Tags: c++, winapi

I can use [SetThreadExecutionState()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208(v=vs.85).aspx) to change execution state of a thread from which I call this function. Is there a way to call this (similar) function to change execution state for another thread, not the one from which I call it.

Actually, the problem is that one dll file (from VLC library) that I use is calling this function to prevent display from turning off. I want to forbid it from doing so. I wanted to call SetThreadExecutionState() for all threads in my process and exclude DISPLAY_REQUIRED flag from their states.

If calling this or similar function for another thread is not possible, then does anyone know another way for achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hook the API call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to call this (similar) function to change execution state for another thread

Not directly, no. It only works in the thread that calls it. You would have to call it in every thread individually. If you don't have access to a given thread (for instance, a thread that the DLL creates internally), you would have to somehow inject code that runs in the context of that thread.  There are various injection techniques available.

> one dll file (from VLC library) that I use is calling this function to prevent display from turning off. I want to forbid it from doing so. I wanted to call SetThreadExecutionState() for all threads in my process and exclude DISPLAY_REQUIRED flag from their states.

Simply hook the function itself (there are plenty of examples and even libraries for hooking API functions) so you can alter the input parameter before forwarding it to the original function.